# drop element in table and change src of already present img

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I am trying to copy drop element in div , but the problem is when i dropped element and change image src of already present attribute , drag element remaining same still drag-able.

[**Fiddle**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Z9HDP/)

js code snippts ::

```
$('.piece').draggable({
    revert: 'invalid',
    start: function (event, ui) {
        // alert('drag start');
        var td_height = $('td').height();
        var draggedID = $(this).width(td_width).height(td_height);
    }
});
$("td").droppable({
    accept: ".piece",
    drop: handleDrop
});

function handleDrop(event, ui) {
    alert('hello' + $(this).attr("id"));
    var drop_src = ui.draggable.attr("src");
    $(this).addClass("ui-state-highlight");
    //$( this ).find( "img" ).attr("src",drop_src);
    $(this).append(ui.draggable.clone().removeClass().addClass('new_piece'));
    ui.draggable.draggable('option', 'revert', false);
}
});
```

Comment: Can you please explain this "drag element remaining same still drag-able." Thanks

Comment: @HarryBomrah it i am able drag element to new position . once dropped it should not  drag

Comment: You can remove the class you ve bind draggable to. after you remove the class or the selecotor, it should not drag.

Answer (score 1):

### Scenario 1:

If we continue from where you left your JSFiddle, there are a number of problems, each of which may have better solutions than shown, but here goes:

### http://fiddle.jshell.net/Z9HDP/1

You are dropping onto a `TD` that already contains an image, but you are not removing the existing image before appending a new one. I assumed you did not want them lining up side-by-side, so have made it remove the existing content of the `TD` first.

You are cloning the dragged object, *which includes its relative offset of the dragging*, but are not removing the `top` and `left` style values. This means your clone is above and to the right of the table (usually off-the-grid in the Fiddle, so not visible). I am removing the top and left offsets.

You are not resetting the position of the original dragged item, which leaves it where you dropped it. I assumed you wanted it back in the palette and there may be a better way, but I just reset the top & left to 0.

```
function handleDrop(event, ui) {

    //alert('drop ' + $(this).attr("id"));
    var drop_src = ui.draggable.attr("src");
    //alert(drop_src);
    $(this).addClass("ui-state-highlight");

    //$( this ).find( "img" ).attr("src",drop_src);
    $(this).empty().append(ui.draggable.clone().removeClass().addClass('new_piece').css("left", "").css("top", ""));

    // Reset position of dragged item
    ui.draggable.css({
        top: "",
        left: ""
    });

    ui.draggable.draggable('option', 'revert', false);

}
```

### Scenario 2:

If you want to go with your original comment, of changing the target source, this appears to work. I am guessing you were just missing the position reset of the dragged item:

### http://fiddle.jshell.net/Z9HDP/3/

```
function handleDrop(event, ui) {

    //alert('drop ' + $(this).attr("id"));
    var drop_src = ui.draggable.attr("src");
    $(this).addClass("ui-state-highlight");

    $(this).find("img").attr("src", drop_src);
    // Reset position of dragged item
    ui.draggable.css({
        top: "",
        left: ""
    });

    ui.draggable.draggable('option', 'revert', false);

}
```